# Button.Click event is not firing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in JQ. I have created this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZ6mY/7/

All I want to do is to show an "ALERT" message when "C" button is clicked. Also I want to know that if you click "7" how you grab the value 7 in a variable in JQ?

Any input is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `btnClear` to `#btnClear`. The `#` tells jquery that the following string is an ID and not a class, selector, etc.

```
$("#btnClear").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

You comment question:

```
$('input:button').click(function () {
   alert(parseInt($(this).val(), 10))   
})
```

this code will look for ALL input buttons and bind this event to them.

Comment: Thanks. That worked...How should I grab the value of 7 in a var seven?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "#" to specify that you are looking to use the id "btnClear".

Comment: Oh, looks like i was late to the party.

Answer (score 1):

You need a number sign to select by id, like `$("#btnClear")`. As for your second questions, all your numbered buttons are calling a function right now like NumPressed(7); So you can just use the parameter passed to that function. If you want to clean up your code though and remove those onclicks. You can also detect the value of the button like `$(selector).val();`

Answer (score 0):

you should change the

```
$("btnClear").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

to

```
$("#btnClear").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Then the jQuery can find the input element with id 'btnClear'.

Is that clear?

The number input elements you placed a function named NumPressed with the click event, so you can do it like normal js.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I did something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SZ6mY/8/

So I'm assuming that in my seven variable the value 7 will be stored. Is this correct?